# How to allow users to search within an iOS app via Siri

Tags: ios, sirikit

We have an app (let's call it *MyOracle*) which contains a lot of useful information for corporate users.

Users would like to search for information in the app like this:

> "Hey Siri - search MyOracle for articles on climate change"

Looking at SiriKit, which appears to only offer a handful of very specific/not very useful intents, it appears this is not possible.

Or is there another approach, using the global search API or speech recognition API?

Comment: You can't use Siri; there isn't an intent that does what you want. You can use Core Spotlight to make your content available to the on-device index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it with shortcuts and custom intents, you can find it with iOS 12 new siri [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/accelerating_app_interactions_with_shortcuts?changes=latest_minor)

With this it's very easy to add our phrases and custom intents with it's handling to the application and siri will get it for us.

`if let shortcut = INShortcut(intent: order.intent) {
    let addVoiceShortcutVC = INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController(shortcut: shortcut)
    addVoiceShortcutVC.delegate = self
    present(addVoiceShortcutVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}`

This worked for me.